# How to calculate and compare symmetry between two objects?

Tags: symmetry

I need to figure out how symmetrical two objects are. Is there an equation that will generate numerical values in regards to symmetry?

I.e object 1 has 0.5 symmetry while object 2 has 0.6 symmetry so therefore these two objects have similar symmetry.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems that any formula would depend heavily on what kind of objects you have and what kinds of symmetry are most important to you.

Comment: @DavidK thank you for the response, I am very new at this objective. I am wanting to compare the faces of animals and general objects like triangles, and squares. This is for machine learning